# how to avoid the input "%" in using jpa2 criteriaBuilder.like

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

like this:

```
criteriaBuilder.like( root.get("prop"), "%"+userInput+"%" )
```

if `userInput` is the character `%` ,how to avoid the query output?

Comment: Can you replace `%` with empty space?

Comment: What does _avoid the query output_ mean?  Is there any validation on characters the user may enter?

Comment: escape the "%" with a slash?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `literal()`, something like this:

```
criteriaBuilder.like( root.get("prop"), "%" + criteriaBuilder.literal( userInput ) + "%" )
```

### EDITED!

Comment: Unfortunately this just uses the toString of the result of `criteriaBuilder.literal( userInput )`, which is meaningless (you'll send up with `%org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.LiteralExpression@42fa1554%`)